# Exportar dados para um arquivo .cfg

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-1.8

Alguém poderia me dar uma exemplo de como exportar os dados do meu models por pk para um arquivo .cfg?

tentei usar `Mymodel.objects.get(pk=pk)` mas não deu muito certo.

Comment: Você quer exportar o objeto para um arquivo? Se for isso você pode usar `Pickle`, `Shelve`, `Marshal` ou `JSON`.

Comment: O que é um arquivo `.cfg`? Isso é algum formato padronizado? Uma maneira de criar arquivos de qualquer formato baseado em texto - não somente HTML, mas também JSON, XML, etc, inclusive texto puro - é usando o sistema de templates. Posso dar um exemplo, se você mostrar qual a estrutura do seu modelo e qual o formato esperado da saída.

Answer (score -2):

Você pode criar um arquivo usando

```
arquivo = open('arquivodeconfig.cfg', 'r')
#assim você pode usar arquivo.read() para aparecer o que está no arquivo
print(arquivo.read())
arquivo = open('arquivodeconfig.cfg', 'w') #ao abrir o arquivo no modo w(Write) ele formata o arquivo
input = input('')
arquivo.write(input) #assim ele escreve um input no arquivo
```

Você também pode usar o modo a(append) para adicionar mais informação depois da informação do arquivo original usando arquivo.append(O que quiser adicionar).
Espero ter ajudado :D